# QPID 0.30 On Ubuntu 14.04 persistence not working

Tags: apache, ubuntu, persistence, qpid

I have installed qpid-0.30 on Ubuntu 14.04. I have compiled the same from source code using the cpp files available in Downloads section.

Everything is working fine. I can connect to QPID, send message and receive too. But I when I restart the process there is no persistence

I am unable to find how to enable the same. The code uses durable queues and persistent messages. Which I can confirm using qpid-stat

Any help or pointers are appreciated

Regards,
Tarun

Comment: did you configure the journal?

Comment: I did find a solution. The problem was that not all the dependencies were resolved and that was causing the build file to ignore the store plugin. After installing all the dependencies. Its all been working fine

I created a gist also for the same

https://gist.github.com/tarlabs/fdb774fa11de316615e3

Comment: Neat! You should probably post an answer and accept it as well, just to help anyone else who's looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find a solution. The problem was that not all the dependencies were resolved and that was causing the build file to ignore the store plugin. After installing all the dependencies. Its all been working fine I created a gist also for the same

http://gist.github.com/tarunlalwani/fdb774fa11de316615e3

```
#!/bin/sh
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
QPID_VERSION=0.32
cd $HOME
echo "Creating new folder for qpid - $HOME/qpid"
mkdir qpid
cd qpid
echo "Downloading QPID Packages"
wget -nc http://www.us.apache.org/dist/qpid/$QPID_VERSION/qpid-cpp-$QPID_VERSION.tar.gz &
wget -nc http://www.us.apache.org/dist/qpid/$QPID_VERSION/qpid-tools-$QPID_VERSION.tar.gz &
wget -nc http://www.us.apache.org/dist/qpid/$QPID_VERSION/qpid-python-$QPID_VERSION.tar.gz &
wait
echo "Extracting all packages"
tar xf qpid-cpp-$QPID_VERSION.tar.gz &
tar xf qpid-tools-$QPID_VERSION.tar.gz &
tar xf qpid-python-$QPID_VERSION.tar.gz &
wait
echo "Packages Extracted"
echo "Installing dependcies"
sudo apt-get -qy install python-pip python
sudo apt-get -qy install pkg-config libaio-dev libdb++-dev libboost-all-dev ruby swig libnss3-dev gcc cmake doxygen libsasl2-dev uuid-dev valgrind e2fsprogs 
echo "Building source files..."
cd qpid-cpp-$QPID_VERSION
mkdir bld
cd bld
cmake ..
cores=`nproc`
make -j$cores
make install
cd $HOME/qpid/qpid-tools-$QPID_VERSION
python setup.py install &
cd $HOME/qpid/qpid-python-$QPID_VERSION
python setup.py install &
wait
```